# Como colocar imagem no centro

Tags: html, css, css3

Tenho um menu e estou tentando colocra a imagem ao centro e deixar 3 links à esquerda e 3 links à direita, usei:

```
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Porém ele so fica alinhado na versão mobile, veja abaixo:

```css
/*Main Menu CSS*/
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.header-area{
 background:#4DC3CF;
}
.header-area .logotipo {
display: inline-block;
line-height: 55px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.main-menu ul{
 text-align: center;
}
.main-menu ul li{
 list-style:none;
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
}
.main-menu ul li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size:18px;
 padding:30px 20px;
 margin:0px;
 color:#fff;
 font-weight: 600;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 transition: .4s;
}
.main-menu ul li a:hover{
 color:#000;
}

/*Dropdown Menu CSS*/
.main-menu ul li ul{
 position: absolute;
 left:0;
 top:100%;
 width:200px;
 z-index: 999;
 transform: scaleY(0);
 transform-origin: top center;
 opacity:0;
 visibility: hidden;
 transition: .4s;
 background:#4DC3CF;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 8px -2px rgb(37, 39, 38);
}
.main-menu ul li:hover ul{
 transform: scaleY(1);
 opacity:1;
 visibility: visible;
}
.main-menu ul li ul li a{
 padding:14px 18px;
}
```

```html
   <header class="header-area">
   <a href="#" class="logotipo"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/eH60XtT.png" alt="logo alt"></a>
        <div class="main-menu">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="">Services</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Service One</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Service Two</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Service Three</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Service Four</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Service Five</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Vi post aqui e até onde entendi era pra estar alinhado por causa do top: 50% e left e translate e o display-inline-block faria ele ficar dentro, porém não funcionou.

Comment: Você consegue fácilmente usando bootstrap. visite:  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/download/

Comment: Conheço o b4, porém nesse caso to usando so HTML e CSS e com B4 vai ter que aplicar o codigo na nav-brand da mesma forma, so não to entendendo o porque o codigo não esta funcioando.

Comment: @GotaB4 sua pergunta está mal formulada e está difícil de entender o que você quer. Consegue reformular a pergunta?

Comment: @KleberOliveira consigo, no caso quero colocar a imagem no meio no menu e deixa os links 3 a direita e  3 a esquerda, posso chama no chat?

Comment: @GotaB4 tentei response com a pergunta reformulada, veja se é a sua necessidade.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Usando a propriedade `display` com o valor `flex`, você terá mais recursos para alinhar os elementos na tela. Utilize  `flex-direction: row;`, `justify-content: center;` e `align-items: center;` para manter todos elementos centralizados e um `@media` para tornar o layout responsivo de acordo com o seu guide.

Segue um exemplo da utilização do valor `flex`:

```css
/*Main Menu CSS*/
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header-area {
  background: #4dc3cf;
}
.header-area .logotipo {
  display: inline-block;
}
.main-menu ul {
  text-align: center;
}
.main-menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.main-menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.main-menu ul li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

/*Dropdown Menu CSS*/
.main-menu ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 999;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: top center;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.4s;
  background: #4dc3cf;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px -2px rgb(37, 39, 38);
}
.main-menu ul li:hover ul {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.main-menu ul li ul li a {
  padding: 14px 18px;
}

.main-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  .main-menu {
flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
  <header class="header-area">

<div class="main-menu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="">Services</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Service One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Service Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Service Three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Service Four</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Service Five</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="logotipo">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/eH60XtT.png" alt="logo alt"></a>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
  </header>
```

Comment: Pra que Flex para algo tão simples? Um simples div com o IMG sendo um elemento nativamente INLINE, bastaria que o DIV, remover o position:absolute (do código autor) pai usa-se `text-align: center;`, não me admira que os sites de hoje cada vezes ficam mais pesados e visualmente ainda simples, é porque as pessoas acreditam mesmo que novas tecnologias vem para substituir o que funciona tão bem, quando na verdade FLEX hora e lugar pra usar de forma proveitosa, você pode escolher ter um tanque de guerra para ir na padaria buscar 6 pães, mas não quer dizer q deva incentivar os outros a isto.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentom concordo :), auxilie o nosso amigo desenvolvedor com a sua solução mais simples. E pode negativar caso achou minha solução muito complexa.

Comment: Entendi, sempre me recomendaram flexbox de forma geral, sou iniciante, vi o codigo no meu não funcionou acho que porque uso jquery e meanmenu, poderia baixar o codigo completo e dar uma olhada? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TlsfuQD6WuENe5H2Q8JaWp_bMDWUjqqI/view          Iria me ser muito util, se quiser chama no chat.

Comment: Não negativo respostas, raramente o faço, só em caso de spam ou de coisa que esta de fato errada, no seu caso não é errado, só não é uma maneira conveniente de solucionar o problema.

Comment: @GotaB4 pra separar os links o problema nem é a imagem e sim o menu, ai é algo que é complicado de resolver, fora que vai depender de como vc deseja q algo seja responvido ou não, me refiro só ao menu, o logo é técnicamente fácil, mesmo o isolando, claro q poderia colocar ele dentro do MENU já resolveria quase tudo, mas a sua pergunta é muito confusa, não dá pra entender bem aonde as coisas tem que ficar;

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento realmente entendi o seu ponto e ficou uma pulga atrás da minha orelha sobre este assunto de usar o flexbox ser algo lento, encontrei este post: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/10/Flexbox-layout-isn-t-slow porem realmente não quero induzir uma pessoa iniciante a cometer algum erro, irei pesquisar a melhor forma de auxiliar alguem.

Comment: @GotaB4 altere o seu HTML também que irá funcionar.

Comment: @KleberOliveira seu ultimo comentário resumiu a melhor possivel solução, refazer. O autor quer remendar e isto é complicado, o melhor seria ele estudar o básico antes de pular pro avançado, na verdade a pergunta deveria estar fechada, pq nem chega a ser um problema bem definido. Os votos de fechamento não são do mal ;)

Comment: @KleberOliveira estou tentando chega nesse resultado: i.imgur.com/B7TmP7P.png 3 links a esquerda 3 a direita e logo no centro testei o snippi e aqui não deu creio que devido aos demais codigo deixei o link do google drive se poder dar uma olhada

Comment: @GotaB4 fatalmente você precisará modificar o seu menu.

Comment: @KleberOliveira sim so altera na parte mobile, acho que é por ter herança, estou usando o meanmenu um mini framework de menu responsivo.

Comment: @KleberOliveira vou fechar o post, boa noite.

Comment: @KleberOliveira Obrigado pelas respostas vou tentar usar outro menu esse é muito complicado

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Obrigado pelas respostas também.

Answer (score 1):

Ou separando os seletores no transform

```
.elemento {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```